# Can anyone explain why I get these results in OrCAD?

Tags: simulation, orcad

[image]

I am new user of OrCAD , and I have a problem in understanding the voltage shown in the red circle.

By logic, the voltage of this point should be:

$$3.3 \mathrm V \times \frac{5 \Omega}{5 \Omega + 5 \Omega} = 1.65 \mathrm V$$

Why do not I get this value in OrCAD ?

Comment: There is some current being drawn by the transistor base, this will cause the voltage divider formula to not work.

Comment: Can you help me or give me an idea for what I have to do to make the voltage divider formula work ?

Comment: If you want to find out why that node is at 876.2mV and not your projected 1.65V, you'll need to solve for the transistor properties to know how much base current is being drawn by the transistor. Then you'll be able to do KCL at that node and calculate the node voltage.

Comment: "...what I have to do to make the voltage divider formula work" You should scale down both R3 and R4 by the same factor. The current drawn by the "divider" from the rail should be much higher than the base current of Q1. Of course it is still an approximation, as the base will always draw *some* current, whereas the divider formula is exact only when the divider is not loaded, i.e. it is connected to an infinite impedance.

Answer (score 5):

You would normally expect the voltage at the transistor base to be **close** to 1.65V since the base current is usually a small fraction of the emitter current, and you can see by inspection that the emitter current is in the 1mA range, and that the base divider operates at a similar current level (same order of magnitude at least) and gain is normally in the hundreds.

However, because the transistors are ***saturated***  (Vce is only about 50mV) the base current is much higher than you would otherwise expect. The transistors cannot provide decent current gain if you don't give them enough collector voltage to work.

If you **reduce** the collector load resistors so that the transistors are no longer saturated you should see that the base voltage increases to much closer to your 1.65V calculation. Imagine if you removed R1/R2 entirely- the transistors would each behave as a diode from the base through 6K\$\Omega\$ to -3.3V.